# Is there a closed form for this distribution (maximum difference between successes and failures in i.i.d. Bernoulli flips)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a series of i.i.d. coin flips:
$$X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n\sim \begin{cases}
      1    &\text{w.p. } p \\
      -1 &\text{else}
   \end{cases} $$

We define $$Y = \max_{i\leq n}\sum_{k=1}^{i}X_k$$

> **Is there a closed form for the distribution of $Y$? (i.e. what is $\Pr[Y=y]$, as a function of $n$ and $p$?)**

Comment: By closed, do you mean a strict definition, or e.g. are things like the Gamma function to be admitted?

Comment: @rasher - Gamma function should work just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Désiré André's reflection principle yields $P(Y\geqslant m)=2P(S\geqslant m)-P(S=m)$ for every $m\geqslant0$, where $S=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, hence $P(Y=m)=P(S=m)+P(S=m+1)$. Since $S=2T-n$ where $T$ is binomial $(n,p)$, one can deduce from this fully explicit formulas for the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: Sorry for delay - x-mas and all, in any case, assuming I have not under-interpreted your question, for n trials with success probability p, the PDF at the integer point z is 0 for Abs[z]>n (obviously) or when parity of n and z differ (both must be odd or even, obviously), and $\frac{\Gamma (n+1) (1-p)^{\frac{n-z}{2}} p^{\frac{n+z}{2}}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (n-z+2)\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+z+2)\right)}$ otherwise.

Comment: @rasher You probably meant to post this as a comment to the question, not to my answer. On the mathematical side, note that the formula you suggest can be simplified since only integer values of $\frac12(n\pm z+2)$ are involved. This leads to binomial coefficients more explicit than some ratios of values of the Gamma function. As an aside, let me note that to provide full formulas as you did is to ruin the choice made in my answer to leave the OP perform the last step of the proof themselves.

Comment: yes, noticed the misplacement. Sorry you feel posting formula diminished your answer, certainly not my intent, I simply did not get any impression the OP desired a hint over an answer. My apologies.